# C# How to find if a single letter matches a letter in a string?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, methods

I would like to ask how can I find if a string (a single letter) matches a string with the same letter on it, on C#. For example:

```
public class Program
{
static void Main()
{
   Console.WriteLine("write the word here!");
   string word = Console.ReadLine();
   
   if (/*condition here*/)
   {
   Console.WriteLine("That's right! Go on!");
   }
   else
   {
   Console.WriteLine("This letter is not in the word! Try again!")
   }
```

From this part I'm not sure how to continue. Let's say the user entered the word ORANGE, how can I tell if he is right if he has wrote O or A and wrong if it was B, for example. Do I need to create a RegEx to acomplish that? I have tried the method Contains(), but I believe it cannot identify a single letter on a string like the example, it would work only if one would write the same word/string I guess. Thanks in advance.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
static void Main()
{
    string SecretWord = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Ok!");
    //string Letter = Console.ReadLine();
    
    List<string> Letter = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < SecretWord.Length + 5; i++)
    {
    Letter.Add(Console.ReadLine());
        
    if (SecretWord.Contains(Letter.ToString()))
    {
    Console.WriteLine("You are right! Go on!");
    }
    else
    {
    Console.WriteLine("Keep trying!");
    }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Use IndexOf string method shown in example on following page : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=net-7.0

Comment: `Contains` should work; I don't understand why you think it doesn't. I also don't understand where you are getting “O or A” from. Show us what you tried.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, Actually Contains() works for this. I believe I was trying like stringLetter.Contains(stringWord) and that why it wasn't working I guess. It must be stringWord.Contains(stringLetter). The code is like a game where User 1 sets a secret word and User 2 must discover the letters or the whole word at once. But I must find out how can I set a limit for User 2 tries. Like a word with 5 letters, a limit of 10 tries. Do I need to create a List<string>() in order to get User 2 tries? But will Contains() work with a List? I have lots of code here but right now I'm stuck in this part.

Comment: We can't see your screen so you'll have to put what you're stuck on in your question or we can't help you.

Comment: Ok, this is the newest code I did. But it's not working properly yet. It's not matching the single letters with the same letters on the word.

Comment: This problem is too difficult for you. [Find a simpler problem](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/). For example, you say you need to “set a limit for User 2 tries”. Can you post code that just does that, with no guessing or finding letters? Worry about guessing after the  “set a limit” problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

It's truly as simple as this:

```
string word = "hello";
char letter = 'e';
bool contains = word.Contains(letter);
Console.WriteLine(contains);
```

That produces `True` onto the console.